# Jessie: RPi 2 - USB audio input does not work (output works)

Tags: usb, audio, raspbian-jessie

I am using a *Plantronics USB Headset* that also has a microphone. I have tried a lot of articles and finally managed to make the headphone work, but the microphone still doesn't work.

Here are current settings:

```
$ cat .asoundrc
pcm.!default {
      type hw
       card 1
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

List of devices shows below:

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: C320 [Plantronics C320], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried searching for `snd_usb_audio` and here is the output:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_usb_audio
snd_usb_audio         114378  4
snd_usbmidi_lib        19690  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep               5595  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm                73442  1 snd_usb_audio
snd                    50779  15 snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device
```

The ALSA blacklist `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-blacklist.conf` contents are:

```
blacklist snd_bcm2835
```

I have added following lines to `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

The mixer settings show:

```
$ amixer -c 0 sget 'Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 4
  Mono: Capture 3 [75%] [4.00dB] [on]
```

But when I use `arecord` it gives this error:

```
$ arecord output.wav
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory

$ arecord -r 16000 -f S16_LE output.wav
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory

$ arecord -D hw:0,0 -f S16_LE test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved this by following commands

```
$ arecord --device=plughw:0,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 test.wav
$ aplay --device=plughw:0,0 test.wav
```

This allows recording from mic and playing on speakers

Alternatively, use this process

```
$ aplay -L
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=C320
    Plantronics C320, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
```

Then choose one of the cards. I chose `sysdefault:CARD=C320` and executed these commands

```
$ arecord -D sysdefault:CARD=C320 test.wav --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 test.wav
$ aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=C320 test.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are setting your default card to be at `1,0` when your mic is listed at `0,0`. Try adding `--device=hw:0,0` to your `arecord` command.

So your command should be:

```
sudo arecord --device=he0,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE output.wav
```

*Note that you do need `sudo` to use `arecord`.*

Comment: Getting this error:
`ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory`

Comment: @PunitGanshani oops, there was a typo in my answer, I fixed it. (I forgot a space.)

Comment: I did add a space and try at the first go, but it did not work :(